# when I use Nativebase getImageSource React native shows me RNVectorIcons module not available

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-native-vector-icons

When I use Native Base vector Icons it shows me "RNVectorIcons module not available"

I'm installing Native Base but not installing RN-Vector-Icons separately

can you find this error it will really help for me or others

[Here the Full Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eK6Z.png)

```
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign'; // for nativeBase getImageSource

const goAuth = () => {
    Promise.all([
        Icon.getImageSource('adduser', 15),
        Icon.getImageSource('login', 15)
    ]).then(source => {
        Navigation.setRoot({
            root: {
                id: 'authSccreen',
                bottomTabs: {
                    children: [{
                        component: {
                            name: 'signIn',
                            options: {
                                text: 'signIn',
                                icon: source[0]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: 'signUp',
                            options: {
                                text: 'signUp',
                                icon: source[1]
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                }
            }
        })
    })
}

export default goAuth
```

and also check this image it shows me GetImageSource is install in Icon import

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRZDp.png)

Answer (score 0):

After  `npm install react-native-vector-icons` You have a link that vector Icon library.
I think you forgot to link that library 
if you are trying for **android** just fire this command

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

and for **ios**

Add the following to your Podfile and run pod update:

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

Edit Info.plist as described above.

If you are using use_frameworks! in your Podfile, you instead need to dynamically load the icon font by doing Icon.loadFont() when bootstrapping your application.

Comment: When i linked the Library it shows me * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details * this error

Comment: @abdulMoiz can you please share full error or screenshot if it.

Comment: Dear When I linked React-native Vector Icons without Installing ```npm install react-native-vector-icons``` it linked successfully and also successfully build for android but display not showing

Comment: you definitely check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRZDp.png it helps you to finding an error maybe

Comment: yes ```react-native link react-native-vector-icons``` same link is was used previously. after the linked my app shows me blank screen in Android Simulator